# Is 30k mile maintenance really required?

Tags: subaru, scheduled-maintenance

Is 30k mile maintenance really required? I have a subaru wrx '09 and the time has come for the check. I called the dealer after going through the manual. They quoted me 500+ for the check which included topping of fluids, and other regular checks (most of which are already done during an oil change). I have read that this kind of check helps detect problems before the warranty runs out. So how big of a deal is to get this done?

Comment: Dealer could avoid the warranty if you miss it (most likely).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is "yes."

The longer answer seems to hinge on the cost.  The 30K mile service on my 2004 WRX included the following:

- Inspect  Drive belt(s) [Except camshaft]
- *Inspect Camshaft drive belt*
- Replace  Engine oil
- Replace  Engine oil filter
- Perform  Replace engine coolant and inspect cooling system, hoses and connections
- Recommended Performance  Replace fuel filter and inspect fuel system, hoses and connections
- Replace  Air cleaner element
- *Replace Spark plugs*
- *Inspect Transmission/Differential (Front & Rear) lubricants (Gear oil)*
- **Replace    Brake fluid**
- **Inspect    Disc brake pads and discs, front and rear axle boots and axle shaft joint portions**
- **Inspect    Brake linings and drums**
- **Perform    Inspect brake lines and check operation of parking and service brake system**
- Inspect  Clutch operation
- Inspect  Steering and suspension
- *Perform Rotate and Inspect Tires*

I've marked in **bold** above the items on this list that, if improperly inspected or not fixed if there was an issue, could lead to **death** (and would probably lead to a failed vehicle inspection or MOT).  Bad brakes = very bad.

I've marked in *italics* above the items on the list that are a pain / have a larger labor cost associated with them.  For example, I rotate my own tires but I don't pretend that it's fun.

While it is true that some of these things would happen on a regular service, you should consider the fact that you've spent a whole lot of money on this vehicle.  A "major" service is still a fraction of the vehicle's total cost.

That said, if you don't like the quote from your service provider, go to another one and get another quote.  Go with the shop that you trust the most.

Following up: if you're an amateur enthusiast and would like to learn some straightforward car maintenance tasks for fun and profit (or, at least, cost avoidance), here is my suggested subset of the big list:

- Replace  Engine oil
- Replace  Engine oil filter
- Replace  Air cleaner element
- *Perform Rotate and Inspect Tires*

None of the above are terribly hard nor are the parts very expensive so they're reasonable learning opportunities.  Also, you can check the detailed service quote and say "please take that off the list, already took care of it."

By the way, one way I judge the quality of the shop is their response to that statement is "great, now I'll be done with your car a little quicker."

Comment: Thanks Bob. I think I'll shop around for a bit and go with it. The thing that threw me off was a dealer in Northern Virginia has quoted me 900 - 1050 for this, which I found to be ridiculous price just to check. He said he would charge extra for important replacements like spark plug.

Comment: @suryalistic, go ahead and ask for a detailed quote.  You will likely find that the plugs are cheap *parts* but an expensive replacement on *some* cars due to the labor.  My car has a flat-4 engine so you can't just reach under the hood and unscrew the plugs.  There's also nothing wrong with learning to do some of the above yourself and saying "please take that off the list, already done."

Comment: the dealer took to offense when I asked him to split the costs and explain why they quoted 1000+ when the neighborhood has dealers with 500+. He refused to take off spark plug out of the routine when I said it is not needed till 60k for turbo models. I am going with the other dealer for now. Just that I trusted the first guy(1000+) with my car for oil changes. The problem with DIY is that I do not have required set up. Thanks for the explanation. What you said is exactly right. The plugs cost me $150, but the labor cost is almost as much. voting up.

Comment: @suryalistic, I feel your pain on the rude dealer.  Still, he did make your decision process easier: "don't come to me for quality service.  Come to me for a rude attitude."  With respect to DIY, some things are less tool-intensive than you might think.  Come over to the dark side....  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I chose to follow the manufactures recommended maintenance scheduled which only requires oil/filter change, air filter and cabin filter change. Dealer quoted 700 for 30K inspection and  90/100 dollars for filter changes. DIY cost for filters was $28 and 30 minutes of my time. Was always told by my Father, who was owner/operator of an independent garage for 40 years, "if it isn't broke, don't fix it". I presently follow the Mfg. maint. schedule and am driving a 25 year old vehicle with 200k miles. Runs good and uses no oil. In the last 15 years it has had less than $600 in maint. cost which includes replacing timing belt and external belts. Still has original spark plugs and starts every time I turn the key. Anyone replacing plugs at 30K miles on todays cars is wasting money unless there is an obvious problem. Just my opinion.

Comment: Don't replace it if it's not worn out, sure. But a huge part of the labour cost for a service is simply getting access to, and inspecting all the bits that can wear out. It might take 45 minutes for me to inspect all the spark plugs on my GSXR, and 5 more minutes to go ahead and replace them if worn.

Comment: @Leliel And of course, if you don't replace them, then the next time you'd have to spend those 45 minutes *again* to get access to the spark plugs...